# I want circles to change color whenever one of them are clicked & have a Stop and Start function together

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var check = null;

function Timer() {
  if (check == null) {
    var count = 10;

    check = setInterval(function () {
      count -= 1;
      document.getElementById("VR").textContent = count;
      if (count <= 0) clearInterval(check);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(check);
  check = null;
  document.getElementById("VR").textContent = "0";
}
```

```html
<div class="VRcircle">
          <div class="text">
            <h1 id="VR">VR</h1>
          </div>
</div>
<div class="circle circle1" onclick="Timer()">
            <div class="text">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Scene</p>
                <span>I</span>
              </a>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="circle circle2" onclick="Timer()">
            <div class="text">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Scene</p>
                <span>II</span>
              </a>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="circle circle3" onclick="stop()">
            <div class="text">
              <a href="#">
                <p>Scene</p>
                <span>III</span>
              </a>
            </div>
</div>
```

1. Circle1, circle2 & circle3 should change color whenever they are clicked and timer should be displayed on VR circle.
2. Would it be possible to start timer when i click on element and on second click stop it while it's running?
3. Could i click different elements without refreshing the page and how ?

Thanks in advance

I can display *Timer()* function on VR circle, i also have written *stop()* function, both of them works.
but can't do other things. my mind went blank probably.
Hope anyone will help me.

Comment: what about trying to make a js that will add /remove a class to your element, then you could use css and transitions to perform the animation you desire. You could also use the css class addition to integrate your timer.